# Need to recover the hard disk space occupied by Linux from Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, linux, ubuntu, partitioning

I purchased a Dell Laptop which came with pre-installed Ubuntu Linux. I installed Windows 7 ultimate.During installation I deleted the existing partitions thinking that would completely remove Linux from my machine.
Now when I start my machine, it takes me to Windows7 as expected. But I think Linux is not completely removed as I find nearly 100 Gb missing 
(My HDD is 320 and C: D: E: comes only to 220).
In the computer management , I see 102Gb unallocated.[image]
How can I remove linux completely from my machine and get lost 100GB back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is unallocated, just create a Windows partition and use it to store data.

If there were Linux in that space, you wouldn't see "unallocated".

Comment: To be more specific - you did delete the partition, but the space then just sits there. "Unallocated" can be read as "unpartitioned". You need to either make a new partition, or extend one of your existing partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Try using open source Gparted

http://gparted.sourceforge.net/

It lets you add partitions, delete partitions, resize partitions.  My experiences have been only using it on non-RAIDed drives.  The tool is fairly versatile. You can use it for a variety of file-system types.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- right-click on the partition you want to extend to fill the extra space (which might only be the E: one; I'm not sure if consumer versions of Windows can span volumes across different partitions) and click Extend Volume.

or

- right-click on the empty space and make a new partition (which will initially present as a new drive on your system, but you can change to be a folder on an existing drive if you so desire)

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the drives you don't use or don't see, Make sure you delete the correct one (DO NOT DELETE C) and then right click and then extend drive add the moste you can and press DONE there you go!

Comment: This is really a comment rather than a solution to what was asked.  With a little more rep, you will be able to post comments.